# How to package application layout into a Ruby gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, view, rubygems, gemspecs

I'm working on a project comprising three different applications. They are supposed to share some models and the outer layout. To avoid code duplication, I'm trying to extract the application layout (`project_name/app/views/layouts/application.html.haml`) into a gem.

I followed these steps:

1. create the base gem structure with `bundle gem common`
2. place the layout file inside `common/app/views/layouts/application.html.haml`
3. wrote the Gemspec descriptors

   ```
   # -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
   require File.expand_path('../lib/common/version', __FILE__)

   Gem::Specification.new do |gem|
     gem.authors       = ["Arthur Alkmim"]
     gem.email         = ["myemail@here"]
     gem.description   = %q{Common project files}
     gem.summary       = %q{Common project files, including layout and migrations}
     gem.homepage      = ""

     gem.files         = `git ls-files`.split($\)
     gem.executables   = gem.files.grep(%r{^bin/}).map{ |f| File.basename(f) }
     gem.test_files    = gem.files.grep(%r{^(test|spec|features)/})
     gem.name          = "common"
     gem.require_paths = ["lib"]
     gem.version       = Common::VERSION
   end
   ```
4. commit the changes
5. `gem build common.gemspec` (successful)
6. `rake install` (successful)
7. Place `gem 'common'` in the project Gemfile

But still the project won't load the application layout. What should I do to tell my project it has to load the layout files through the gem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about using git submodules or svn externals? If you go the gem route you'll have to build/install whenever there's a change.

Comment: @KreeK Submodules and externals are kind of a pain. It's easier to deal with gems in my experience -- just run `bundle install` and off you go. Git submodules in particular are extremely annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sort of solved it. I changed `application.html.haml` to `common.html.haml` and placed the relevant layout call in the ApplicationController. Seems like Rails won't let me package the application.html layout in a gem, but other layouts are okay. If somebody comes up with a better solution (less workaround-ish), please post!

Comment: I would provide a generator for your gem. Have it replace `application.html.haml` with your version. Something like `rails g common:install`

Comment: I think it would be more troubling than simply decorating the controller. I'd have to re-run the generator everytime I updated the gem, and be troubled again by code duplication.

Comment: Out of curiosity - did you delete `app/views/layouts/application.html.haml` in the applications which use the gem?

Answer (score 1):

Have you added your gem to your Rails Gemfile to include it in your application?

You can use the path option to specify a relative path in development. e.g.

```
gem 'common', :path => "../path/to/gem"
```

Don't forget to then run `bundle install`